# what is the field "Name" useful in crypto-config.yaml

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ca

from file crypto-config.yaml, some snippet is as following:

```
 OrdererOrgs:  
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  # Orderer  
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  - Name: OrdererAA  
    Domain: example.comwwww  
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    Specs:
      - Hostname: ordererCC
```

When I execute

> cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

It generate msp files， but I do not find something related to field Name?
What is field Name useful?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a convenience key in the yaml file.  It is not used in the generated output